# Convert TelegramDesktop profile to telegram-cli

Tags: telegram

Telegram Desktop by default during registration creates a folder "tdata" in the user's home directory. It contains files for authorization.

Auth-file is required for authorization in telegram-cli. It is created when I log in to telegram-cli and enter the code from Telegram Desktop.
Perhaps there is a way to log in to telegram-cli using files from the "tdata" folder or is it possible to translate them somehow?

Comment: What is exactly you're trying to do? Do you have any code samples?

Comment: I do not have code examples, I have not yet written a program shell. While I want to deal with authorization. I need to write an automation for the site. I get the tdata folder, which I can put next to the executable file and will be authorized in Telegram.

But since I need authorization in telegram-cli, I need auth file.

Comment: I hope this helps: https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/readthedocs/extra/advanced-usage/sessions.rst